# Selecting a listview row with a checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, api, data-binding

I'm calling an api into a WPF listView. I added a `CheckBox` to each row and am trying to select a row the `CheckBox` and then display that value.

My xaml file:

```
            <ListView x:Name="myListView"  
                      SelectedValue="{Binding title}" 
                      Height="550" Margin="35,149,-202.2,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Background="AntiqueWhite" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"                   
                      SelectionChanged="MyListView_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>                
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <CheckBox 
                                Name="myCheckBox"
                                Click="listView_Click"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                                Margin="5, 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding publisher}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding price}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
            </ListView>
```

And my `listView_Click` method, with what I've tried and the output it produced

```
    private void listView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Selected_label.Text = myListView.ItemsSource.ToString();
        //Output = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShortBoxedUI.ShortBoxed+Comics]

        //Selected_label.Text = myListView.Items.ToString();
        //Output = System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection

        //Selected_label.Text = myListView.ToString();
        //Output = System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:352                
     }
```

I checked the past questions/answers and didn't find anything that aligned with what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `DataTemplate` in `ListView.ItemTemplate` will bind to the data item from `ItemsSource`. If you want to bind to the `ListViewItem` itself (which is housing the `DataTemplate`), you can use [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource):

```
...
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
...
```

The correct property to get the currently selected item is [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem), while `SelectedValue` would only be used in conjunction with `SelectedValuePath`.

And the event for doing something when the selected item changes is [`SelectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged).

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataObject selectedItem = myListView.SelectedItem;
    Selected_label.Text = selectedItem.SomeTextProperty;
}
```

Commonly, though, you would bind to `SelectedItem` rather than handle `SelectionChanged` directly.